# Selecting items by month in a set which spans multiple months in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do this. Basically I have Transaction objects which have a dateCreated property -- The Transaction objects in total span about 5 months, with several Transactions in each month. I need to take the earliest date and the latest date in the set and select the Transactions by month -- so I need a list of Transactions for each month.

Ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
def transactionsByMonth = transactions.groupBy { it.dateCreated.format("yyyy-MM") }
```

Assuming you hold all transactions in a List, this would give you a Map having an entry for each month with a List of corresponding transactions as its value.